# How to get a value out of a register on the cpu

Tags: c, cpu-registers

I want to get the value of a register on the CPU, I looked on the spec sheet and found the address (0xE000E018) and I want to name the variable I store the value in "subticks_per_tick"

This is on a TWR-K65F180M running FreeRTOS.

```
register uint64_t 0xE000E018 asm ("subticks_per_tick");
register uint64_t subticks_per_tick asm ("0xE000E018");
```

first line gets: error: expected identifier or '(' before numeric constant

second line gets: invalid register name for 'subticks_per_tick'

Comment: The C `register` keyword does not associate a variable directly with a register.  If that's a feature provided as an extension by your compiler then you'll need to consult your compiler's documentation to determine how to use it, or at minimum tell us what compiler that is.

Comment: It looks like an attempt to use the GNU C extension for manual register allocation: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Explicit-Register-Variables.html

Comment: The big difference from all of the GNU C examples is that  registers are supposed to have names like `eax` or `r1`, not addresses like `0xE000E014`.

Comment: Where is the spec sheet you refer to?

Comment: This doesn't sound like you are dealing with a CPU register. Your name 'subticks_per_tick' sounds like it might be a timer register, or, even more likely, an RTOS constant or variable. Very specifically and precisely where are you getting this address from?

Comment: This address is from the CPU Manual

Comment: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0439b/DDI0439B_cortex_m4_r0p0_trm.pdf page 52 STCVR register

Comment: The manual shows the address of the STCVR is 0xE000E018. Why are you using 0xE000E014? Also, when you respond to somebody, include a tag for their user name with “@” so that Stack Overflow will notify them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about FreeRTOS or your hardware but:

1. This looks like an address and not the register name (probably the register is mapped there)
2. Variable name can't start with a number therefore `0xE000E014` can't be a name hence the error

What you should probably do to get this register's values is:

```
volatile uint32_t *subticks_per_tick = (volatile uint32_t *) 0xE000E014;
```

and then read the value by dereferencing this pointer.

Comment: Plausible, but it's poor form to answer with a guess.

Comment: A hexadecimal address ending with `4` is unlikely to be the address of a 64-bit register.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, why shouldn't I share information that might help the OP solve their problem even if it's a guess? For me it was a choice between answering with a guess or answering in the comment section.

Comment: @r3musn0x, because it's **not an answer**, it's a guess. It might help the OP, but it might also waste their time, and perhaps also that of many other people who see it later.  We sometimes give mistaken answers here, but you've no business writing an answer that you're not confident about when you post it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, so you are saying that if I see a question that I don't know the exact answer to but I have an idea about how would I try to solve this problem I should just keep it to myself and not try to help the OP?

Comment: @r3musn0x: You can write a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: I am saying that you should not present such ideas as an answer to the question.  You could consider commenting on the question to either suggest things for the OP to try or to ask them for clarification that will help you formulate a *bona fide* answer.  You can consider doing some research to firm up your guess into an answer (or refute it).  But an answer should be definitive.

Comment: In any case were this correct then the pointed to by type should be volatile- qualified

Comment: Also I was wrong this was actually a 32-bit integer